# Self made ruby timer inside thread

Tags: ruby, multithreading, session

I am attempting to create a session timeout system for a client/server networking project. What happens is the client connects and as it authenticates the server creates a session object that holds the timeout, the session id, and a thread handle. From here the client sends a keep alive packet every so often and the server will access this session object and reset the timeout.

Here is some code and I will explain each function at the bottom:

nodeCache.rb

```
@nodeCache   = []

def nodeAdd(nodeName)
    nodeHash = {:nodeName => nodeName, :session => createSession(nodeName)}
    @nodeCache.push(nodeHash)

    return true
end

def nodeKeepAlive(nodeName)
    @nodeCache.each do |node|
        if node[:nodeName].eql? nodeName
            session = node[:session]
            session.timer.thread_variable_set(:expire, 10)
            return true
        end
    end

    return false
end
```

The `nodeAdd` method simply takes a node ID and creates a hash to store in an array so that I may easily keep track of future data relating to that node.

The `nodeKeepAlive` function iterates through the array of node hashes searching for the node that gave the keep alive, and once found it grabs its session object and tries to reset the thread so that the timer resets back to default.

NodeSession.rb

```
require "thread"

class Session
    attr_reader   :nodeName
    attr_accessor :expire, :timer

    def initialize(nodeName)
        @nodeName = nodeName
        @expire   = 10
        @timer    = nil
    end
end

def start(session)
    expire = session.expire
    alive  = true

    while (expire -= 1) > 0
        puts "timer tick #{expire}"
        sleep(1)
    end

    puts "timer expired"
    alive = false 
end

def createSession(nodeName)
    session = Session.new(nodeName)
    session.expire = 10
    session.timer = Thread.new { start(session) }
    return session
end
```

The `Session` class is an object that stores the node name, the expire timeout, and the thread handle.

The `start` method is the method the thread uses to decrement the expire time and if it reaches 0 it will notify me that the session for that node has timed out (eventually).

The `createSession` method creates a new session object, initializes it, and starts the thread that starts counting down and returns the session object to be stored in the node cache array of hashes.

---

The problem I am facing is I can not manage to reset the timer from outside the thread. I have tried using the fiber local variable assignment, the thread local variable assignment (thread_variable_set/get) and simply attempting to reset the expire on the session object I can't figure out how to do this. If anyone could lead me to some documentation or reading on how to change local variables inside a thread it would be appreciated. I would even accept if someone could outline a better way to setup a keep alive system similar to this setup.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you other abordage to your problem. I'll keep it by high because this is a very long question.

When creating the session, take the current time with `Time.now` and store it in an attribute `last_access`.

When using the session:

```
if Time.now > (last_access + max_time)
  # close the session and ask for open a new one
else
  last_access = Time.now
  #allow to continue
end
```

Comment: Using this with a few modifications to work on an external thread served its purpose. Thanks.